# Getting Text and Location of annotations of a pdf page with Syncfusion WinRT library

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, syncfusion

In a windows store app project i use Syncfusion for WinRT library

i have this code to add annotations to a pdf page

```
                ....
                var page = pdfDocument.Pages[pagn];
                ....
                string pdfAnnotationMsg = "Test Annotation 123";
                PdfPopupAnnotation popupAnnotation = new PdfPopupAnnotation(new RectangleF((float)x, (pageHeight * 1.325f) - (float)y - VertOff2, 5, 5), pdfAnnotationMsg);
                popupAnnotation.Border.Width = 1;
                popupAnnotation.Open = false;
                popupAnnotation.Border.HorizontalRadius = 1;
                popupAnnotation.Border.VerticalRadius = 1;
                popupAnnotation.Icon = PdfPopupIcon.Comment;
                page.Annotations.Add(popupAnnotation);
```

The annotation gets added correctly but now im trying to access to its content and location 
I have this variable :

```
PdfLoadedAnnotationCollection annotationCollection = pdfDocument.Pages[0].Annotations;
```

and its count number shows the correct ammount of annotations, but if i use

```
annotationCollection[0].Text
```

i get the following exception:

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Syncfusion.Pdf.WinRT.DLL" Exception

[image]

How do i properly get the Text and Location from the diferent Annotations ?

Answer (score 1):

Annotations will be added only after saving the PDF document, Please save the PDF document before loading the Annotation collection. I have attached the code snippet for your reference.

```
        var page = doc.Pages[pagn];
        string pdfAnnotationMsg = "Test Annotation 123";
        PdfPopupAnnotation popupAnnotation = new PdfPopupAnnotation(new RectangleF((float)x, (pageHeight * 1.325f) - (float)y - VertOff2, 5, 5), pdfAnnotationMsg);
        popupAnnotation.Border.Width = 1;
        popupAnnotation.Open = false;
        popupAnnotation.Border.HorizontalRadius = 1;
        popupAnnotation.Border.VerticalRadius = 1;
        popupAnnotation.Icon = PdfPopupIcon.Comment;
        page.Annotations.Add(popupAnnotation);

        //Save the PDF document
        MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream();
        doc.Save(ms);
        doc.Close(true);

        //Load the PDF document again
        doc = new PdfLoadedDocument(ms);
        PdfLoadedAnnotationCollection annotationCollection = doc.Pages[0].Annotations;
        var text = annotationCollection[0].Text;
```

Please let us know if you have any concern.